# How is the phrase 'as...as' used?

Tags: phrase-usage, phrases, as

My question is, there is some phrase which (at this moment) I cannot exactly remember, but the syntax is following -

> as *_* as

Here, (__) is some word. Such phrases are very confusing to me. Can somebody explain me? These phrases don't have a literal translations in Spanish.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Wow!  That is a long string of words.

Comment: ok, so what atributtes give as __ as (as before and after a word) to a word, or in wholes phrases is different

Comment: Please word your question **very** carefully, using punctuation. It's currently very hard to understand.

Comment: Premier, I'm sure if you word the question in Spanish you will have more chances to have an answer, though.

Comment: Oh!  Like: "This question makes me **as happy as a clam!**"  (I suppose clams look like they're smiling.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> A is as B as C

It's the comparison syntax, which means that A has an attribute B similar to C.

For example:

> Mary is as tall as Jane

Jane and Mary have similar height.

Or negation:

> I'm not as fluent in Spanish as you

You certainly speak Spanish  better than I.

See also Lenka's song which contains a lot of metaphorical comparisons:

> As sly as a fox, as strong as an ox
>   As fast as a hare, as brave as a bear
>   As free as a bird, as mean as a word
>   As quiet as a mouse, as big as a house

(Full lyric for example [here](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/l/lenka/everything_at_once.html))

Comment: thanks a lot, I know which my question was hard to understand. But this is the answer I expected.

Answer (score 1):

My car is not as big as the other one.
Mi auto no es tan grande como el otro.

'As ... As' se traduce al español  'Tan ... Como'. Cuando haces una comparacion entre dos cosas.

Answer (score 0):

First, I hope that I understood what you wanted to ask. If this is not what you exactly meant, you can write a comment and I shall delete/edit the question.

But then, if this is what you meant, the question is too broad to explain. But, you should at least understand that this structure is widely used to mean that *something/body* is *like something/body.* See here -

> Mary is *as good as* Julie in studies - They have (nearly) same expertise in studies.

To mean that something/body is NOT like something/body, you use it by putting 'not' as [here](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/193858-Use-of-quot-not-as-adjective-as-quot). In addition, the phrase can also be used to mean *nearly* or even *uncertainty* as described [here](http://www.usingenglish.com/forum/threads/57481-meaning-of-as-adjective-as-structures).

Please note that this is just one use of *as + adjective + as*. Refer some good dictionary to learn more. I just tried to make you understand the commonest use of the phrase *as...as*.